# how to stop empty html elements from being dimensionless?

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE:**

I found that floating `#name` to the left fixed my issue. Strangely it remains centered. I don't understand why this should be.. but it works now.

---

I have a web app that uses AJAX to update a `<p>` element with some text generated by a script.
When the page loads initially, the `<p>` is empty (`<p id="name"></p>`). There are two other elements below it, all centered inside a `<div>`, they are an `<img>` and a `<p>` respectively.

**Here is the html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Name Generator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/name.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="name"> </p><br/>
            <p id="title">GENERATE YOUR NAME</p>
            <img id="button" src="static/generator.png"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and the CSS:**

```
body {
/*border: 1px dashed white;*/
position:relative;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
background-image:url('static/background-soundproof.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}

div {
/*border: 1px dashed blue;*/
text-align: center;
width:  400px;
height: 600px;
margin: auto;
}

#name {
color:black;
text-shadow:0 0 12px white;
text-transform:capitalize;
font-family: Impact, Sans-Serif;
font-weight:100;
font-size:2.5em;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 60px;
}

#title{
font-family:Courier, sans-serif;
font-size:1.5em;
color:#7D7DBD;
position: relative;
top: 400px;
}

img {
margin: auto;
position: relative;
top:150px;
}
```

My problem is, when the page first loads, the first `<p>` is empty, and because of this, it doesn't seem to have any dimensions. When the `<img>` is clicked, the `<p>` is updated with some text, and this causes the elements below it to shift down the page by about the height of the newly updated `<p>`. Is there a way that I can load the page so that the empty element has fixed dimensions, which it keeps when updated. So it's dimensions will basically never change and nothing is shifted around by it.

I have tried giving it width and height, padding and a margin in css, to no avail. I have also tried having it initially filled in with a `'&nbsp'` which I read somewhere might do the trick, but it didn't. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You could add `min-height` for `#name`.

Comment: @mdesdev It doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: I notice that if I float all the elements in the div either left or right, the problem goes away. The two lower elements float to either side, and the first p stays centered... odd

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/t463z/)

add this to your css

```
p#name{
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Edit:

```
p#name{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
```

}

Comment: then try using display: inline-block; and min-width @Totem

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think I've fixed the problem. See my update. Incidentally, I tried this also, but it didn't work